# Bitmap.Save vs File.WriteAllBytes

Tags: c#, file, graphics, bitmap

I have a byte array (imgBuffer) which contains the rgb values for a jpeg image. I would like to save this to a Bitmap. When I use `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("fileImg.jpg", imgBuffer);` I am able see the image in my directory in its correct format. The image gets corrupted when I try to write the same byte array, imgBuffer, to a Bitmap object. (The image format is 24bpp, 320x240)

```
BitmapData data;
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(320, 240, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
//convert bytes to a bitmap
data = myBitmap .LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmapResized.Size), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                  PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Marshal.Copy(imgBuffer, 0, data.Scan0, imgBuffer.Length);
myBitmap .UnlockBits(data);
myBitmap .Save("bitmapImg.jpg");
```

What must I change so that bitmapImg is correctly outputted to my directory? I am currently getting the following corrupted image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can save your `imgBuffer` byte array to disk and read it as a JPEG in an image viewer, then it is not the raw RGB values for the image.

You can load a `Bitmap` from a stream and use the data in `imgBuffer` as your source, and you will get a `Bitmap` object back that you can use.

Comment: That solved the problem! I guess my `imgBuffer`contained some header data that I was not aware of. Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is that the `Bitmap` code assumes the data is in the bitmap format.  The Save method first converts that to jpg and then saves it out.  In this case it is already in the jpg format hence converting jpg to jpg is corrupting the image.  In the `File.WriteAllBytes` method it just directly saves hence there is no corruption

Comment: I have also tried to save the bitmap using `myBitmap.Save("bitmapImg.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)` but am still receiving a corrupted image. In fact the image size is even smaller than before. I am assuming it is not recognizing the order of my bytes and therefore re-encoding and compressing the bits to a jpeg again.